# using card layout to change pane with only one button

Tags: java, swing, cardlayout

I have a gui that uses card layout as layout manager.this gui has two button prev and next to change view. I would know if it is possible using CardLayout change card only having one button.

Comment: 1) It is not clear what this one button should do. Is it supposed to show the next component? the previous one? Explain the behaviour expected when you press that button 2) Show us what you've got so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: It is very possible to have a `CardLayout` controlled by a single button, the question is what the button should do. What have you tried, and how did it break?

Comment: The button should show the next component...

Comment: Can't you simply remove the 'previous' button then? Again, please show your code.

Comment: @JacobRaihle Thanks...it was much easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Adapted from my comment)*

It's definitely possible. If you want the same functionality as one of the existing buttons, just remove the other one and you're set!